# How to verify registrations on Server side implementation of GCM Push Notifications?

Tags: java, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

**My Case**

- Android/iOS app using phonegap
- Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)
- Using Phonegap plugin [Push Notifications](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to receive downstream notifications
- Dropwizard on server side
- App content available free without registration/login on my servers

**Problem**

Currently, I'm stuck at server side implementation since I have to store registrations Ids on my server as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) (check the `ToDo` of this line `sendRegistrationToServer(token);`)

I haven't found any documentation on how to properly store the Id's and it seems to be impossible to retrieve those registration ids from the GCM network.

From what I have read I need to implement the way I post `Ids` to my app server from my clients.

I need to ensure that those `Ids` are securely stored in my server app. That said:

1. What's the best practice to post `registrationIds` to my server app?
2. How do I know if the post request to register a new client `registrationId` is truly from my app's client on my server app since I can't link it to any kind of login? (app available to everyone) In order to not storing any `registrationIds` not related to my app and therefore not sending notifications to unknown and unwanted devices.
3. Is there any tutorial on how to implement a *"real enterprise-ready app server"* using GCM Push notifications?
4. Do my questions have sense or I'm in a totally wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The simplest way I could think of is setting up an HTTPS servlet on the server to receive registration ids from your clients and store them.
2. I think there is no way to know that it's your app (and that it wasn't tempered with) for sure, but why would you care? In the worst case attacker may feed you some invalid registration ids that you'll clear after attempting to send GCM message and receiving appropriate errors in response.
3. An HTTP server, HTTP client and database to store relation between users and registration ids; the overall scheme doesn't seem too complicated
4. Totally make sense to me.

Comment: After further reading on GCM, I found what you mention on point 3. I see it's designed to prevent and autoclean trash requests because of the needed `registrationId` and I guess it would be useless if no one has my apikey, is that right?

Comment: @Cyberdelphos not sure what you mean, but API key is used to authenticate your server with GCM servers, so as long as you keep it secret, no one else will be able to send GCM notifications to your clients.